# What is the concatenation of this language with itself?

Tags: math, regular-language, finite-automata, automata, formal-languages

Given the following language:

> `L1 = { (ab)n | n ≥ 0 }`

That is, `L1 = { ε ab, abab, ababab, abababab, ... }`

The question is to find what language `L12` is.

My guess is that it's equal to `{ (ab)2n | n ≥ 0 }`. Is that correct? If so, how do I prove it? If not, why not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The language L<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> is the language of all strings of the form xy, where x ∈ L<sub>1</sub> and y ∈ L<sub>1</sub>. Note that x and y don't have to be the same strings; they can be chosen independently.

In fact, one option is that y = ε, since ε = (ab)<sup>0</sup>. Therefore, any string in L<sub>1</sub> must also belong to L<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>, because we can always concatenate that string with ε.

Moreover, we can show that any string in L<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> is also in L<sub>1</sub>. Take any string w ∈ L<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>. It must have the form xy for some strings x, y ∈ L<sub>1</sub>. This means that we can write w = xy = (ab)<sup>n</sup>(ab)<sup>m</sup> for some natural numbers n and m.  Accordingly, w = (ab)<sup>n+m</sup>, and so w in L<sub>1</sub>.

We just proved that L<sub>1</sub> ⊆ L<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> and that L<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> ⊆ L<sub>1</sub>, from which we get that L<sub>1</sub> = L<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>. This means that L<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup> is the same language as L<sub>1</sub>.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So is L1^(5) a language of ALL strings of the form vwxyz, where v∈ L1, w∈ L1, x∈ L1, y∈ L1, z∈ L1?

Comment: @SajSeesSound Yep!